# Group values by month in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have this table in Access.

```
Date               Total
11/09/2014          1000 €
15/09/2014          5000 €
15/10/2014          5000 €
23/10/2014          10000 €
```

The field "Date" is of date type. I need a method (probably a macro?) that analyze the data in the table based on the date, summing the values in the "total" field and outputs the result on a textbox in a mask.

Example of output based on the table above:

```
September 2014 6000€
October 2014 15000 €
```

[Here](http://wikisend.com/download/594926/Database2.accdb) is the actual database (filled with fake data) if anyone want to have a look. The three tables that need the method are "Manodopera", "Merci_Materiali_Fatture" and "Merci_Materiali_Schede_Lavoro"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to sum the totals grouping by Month and Year.  Here is a query that does it from you table Manodopera:

```
SELECT Format([Mese],"mmmm") + " " + Format([Mese],"yyyy") AS [Date], Sum(Manodopera.Costo_Totale) AS SumOfCosto_Totale
FROM Manodopera
GROUP BY Format([Mese],"mmmm")+" "+Format([Mese],"yyyy");
```

You would need to create that Query for each table you want to Sum by Month and Year.

Comment: The + operator can be replaced by &